# Aws s3 lambda trigger is working weird. Delete action triggers the create action

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm using aws lambda for resizing images.

I've set it up so that if a s3 object is created, lambda function is triggered. But, whenever delete images in bucket on watching.

Although it's not a creation event, lambda function is called.

Is the delete action count as s3 object creation?

Comment: Is versioning enabled on you bucket by any chance?

Comment: Capture and log one of these events.  Show us what it looks like.

Comment: Same here. Any solution?